# How to write an output of a command to stdout and a file in Python3?

Tags: python

I have a Windows command which I want to write to stdout and to a file. For now, I only have `0` string writen in my file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#! -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import subprocess

with open('auto_change_ip.txt', 'w') as f:
    print(subprocess.call(['netsh', 'interface', 'show', 'interface']), file=f)
```

Comment: have you tried to discard the subprocess and simply write any string literal instead?

Comment: Now I have and it works so I edited the title of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.call` returns an int (the returncode) and that's why you have `0` written in your file.
If you want to capture the output, why don't you use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead?

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['netsh', 'interface', 'show', 'interface']
p = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
with open('my_file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(p.stdout)
```

In order to capture the output in `p.stdout`, you'll have to redirect stdout to [`subprocess.PIPE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE).
Now `p.stdout` holds the output (in bytes), which you can save to file.

---

Another option for Python versions < 3.5 is [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor). The main difference for this case is that `.stdout` is a file object, so you'll have to read it.

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['netsh', 'interface', 'show', 'interface']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = p.stdout.read()
#print(out.decode())  
with open('my_file.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(out)
```

Comment: Thank you! What does `subprocess.PIPE` mean? Unfortunately, I use Python 3.4.3 for XP compatibility, but `subprocess.run` is only for 3.5+. Can I import it somehow from future? I don't know how to patch it like suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590192/getting-an-error-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-run-while

Comment: This doesn't write to console too, so I added `subprocess.call(cmd)`. Thank you for explaining a diffrence between `call`, `run` and `popen`.

Comment: Yes, it won't print because the output is redirected. But why don't you use `print`  instead of calling the command twice? I updated my code to give an example.