# How to get the output from executing shell commands in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to execute this shell command using `python`

but the problem is, it doesn't give the output even if there is a wrong or not:

This is what I have tried:

```
get_ns_p1 = subprocess.Popen(['kubectl', 'get', 'ns'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
get_ns_p2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-E", "\'(^|\s)"+NAMESPACE+"($|\s)\'"], stdin=get_ns_p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

get_ns_p1.stdout.close() # Allow proc1 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc2 exits.
out_ns, err = get_ns_p2.communicate()

print("output: " + out_ns)
print("error: " + err)
```

The output looks like:

> output:
>
> error:

but in the terminal itseld, it shows an output like this:

> Error from server (AlreadyExists): namespaces "namespace-tests" already exists

**how can I this error to my `err` variable?**

Comment: Running `grep` in a subprocess is silly anyway. Just `re.search(r'(?:^|\s){}(?:\s|$)'.format(NAMESPACE))` on the `stdout` from `subprocess.run(['kubectl', 'get', 'ns'], text=True, capture_output=True)`

Comment: Can you give me a working example please I am new to python.

Comment: I almost did. Which parts are you having trouble with? See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188

Comment: ... But if what you are looking for is an error message, you should be examining `stderr`.

Comment: what is `re` here?

Comment: besides I am using `python 2.7` and it doesn't have a method called `run()` so this solution doesn't work unless I change my python version (which I don't want to).

Comment: Should I post that link again or can you click on the one I already left in my previous comment?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works correctly; the problem is that you are attempting to capture a string which is emitted on `stderr` if `kubectl` is at all correctly written.

However, running `grep` as a separate subprocess is quite inefficient and unnecessary anyway; Python itself features a much more featureful and complete regular expression engine in the [`re` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) which also lets you avoid the overhead of starting a separate process.

```py
import re

r = re.compile(r'(?:^|\s){}(?:\s|$)'.format(NAMESPACE))

kube = subprocess.run(['kubectl', 'get', 'ns'], text=True, capture_output=True)
e = []
for line in kube.stderr.split('\n'):
    if r.search(err):
        e.append(line)
err = '\n'.join(line)
```

If you are confined to an older version of Python which doesn't have `subprocess.run()`, you have to reimplement it, poorly.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['kubectl', 'get', 'ns'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out_ns, err = p.communicate()
e = []
for line in err.split('\n'):
    ...
```

This has a number of flaws and drawbacks; you really should be thinking seriously about upgrading to Python 3.5+.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590192/getting-an-error-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-run-while for a better reimplementation.