# When using wifi_profile to get ssid it says this IndentationError: expected an indented block on some line

Tags: python, python-2.7

The line `wifi_profile["ssid"] = name` is not letting the code run. It says

> IndentationError: expected an indented block.

Make the line correct so that It can pass.

```
import subprocess

import re

command_output = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()

profile_names = (re.findall("All User Profile       : (.*)\r", command_output))

wifi_list = list()

if len(profile_names) != 0:
    for name in profile_names:
        wifi_profile = dict()

        profile_info = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()

        if re.search("Security key           : Absent", profile_info):
            continue
        else:
        
        wifi_profile["ssid"] = name
        
        profile_info_pass = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name, "key=clear"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
        

        password = re.search("Key Content            : (.*)\r", profile_info_pass)

        if password == None:
            wifi_profile["password"] = None
        else
            wifi_profile["password"] = password[1]
        wifi_list.append(wifi_profile)

for x in range(len(wifi_list)):
    print(wifi_list[x])
```

Comment: Remove the `else:` above, if there's no code below. And another typo: add a `:` after the last `else` (`if password == None:`).

Comment: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590192/getting-an-error-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-run-while – Do you use python2?

Comment: Yes I am using 2.7 and still the error same when i change the parameters. .call( with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess
import re

command_output = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()

profile_names = (re.findall("All User Profile       : (.*)\r", command_output))

wifi_list = list()

if len(profile_names) != 0:
    for name in profile_names:
        wifi_profile = dict()

        profile_info = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
        if re.search("Security key           : Absent", profile_info):
            continue
        else:
            wifi_profile["ssid"] = name
        
        profile_info_pass = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name, "key=clear"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
        password = re.search("Key Content            : (.*)\r", profile_info_pass)

        if password == None:
            wifi_profile["password"] = None
        else: # <----- missing colon
            wifi_profile["password"] = password[1] # <----- this line was not properly indented

        wifi_list.append(wifi_profile)

for x in range(len(wifi_list)):
    print(wifi_list[x])
```

Comment: command_output = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'